# Asian movie where the final scene shows a family having dinner immediately before the nuclear apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, movie, apocalypse, nuclear-weapons

I'm looking for a movie that I saw on the German TV station Kabel Eins probably in the early 2000s. The movie itself should be much older - from what I remember about the look, I'd guess that it's from some time between the 60s and 80s (a wide range, I know, but my memory doesn't arrange for a more precise guess). It definitely was in color. I think I only saw the end, maybe even only the last five minutes of the movie.

The movie was set in Asia (probably Japan) and all of the actors and actresses were Asian. I cannot remember the reason, but the world was on the verge of a nuclear war, and we are experiencing the situation through the point of view of a man and his family. The man may have something to do with the government or the military. At the end of the movie, it seems inevitable that nuclear bombs will start falling shortly, but the general public may not be aware of that. The man chooses to have a normal dinner with his family for maybe the last time (I think they are sitting at a Chabudai, but I may be wrong). The children are unaware of the situation, the wife knows at least something, but I remember her to be more optimistic. The man himself is devastated and has to leave the table and goes to the bathroom to cry. Maybe his wife comes to console him. I'm not sure about the exact sequence of events, but shortly after that, the movie cuts to multiple explosions of nuclear bombs and the destruction they cause. No happy ending at all.

Any chance that this is enough to identify the movie?

Disclaimer: Since I didn't see the entire film, I'm not sure whether it can even be called a science fiction film or just an apocalyptic drama movie.

Answer (score 19):

***[The Last War](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055428/)*** (1961)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_War_(film)):

> *The Last War* (Japanese: 世界大戦争, Hepburn: *Sekai Daisensō*, lit. 'The Great World War') is a 1961 Japanese tokusatsu science-fiction film directed by Shūe Matsubayashi. Produced and distributed by Toho, it was the Toho's second highest-grossing film in Japan that year.

> **The film begins with a narration over shots of a modern-day Tokyo, noting that 16 years have passed since the end of World War II, and Japan has achieved rapid recovery. Mokichi Tamura works as a driver for a press center, hoping for happiness for his family.** His daughter, Saeko, is in love with a merchant, Takano, who has been at sea for a long time. When he returns, the young couple agrees to get married with the consent of Saeko's father.
>
> **Meanwhile, tensions between the Federation and the Alliance (fictional stand-ins for the United States/NATO and the USSR/Warsaw Pact, respectively) build, especially after an intelligence-gathering vessel is captured.** A new Korean War breaks out across the 38th parallel, with the Federation and Alliance drawn into the war. Tensions reach a critical level; dogfights between Federation and Alliance fighters over the Arctic Ocean (with both sides using nuclear-tipped air-to-air missiles) are just the beginning of a renewed conflict. Two Federation and Alliance ICBMs are nearly launched, though both are halted. Although Japan calls on both sides to seek peace, government officials think that the country could be ripe for Alliance retaliation in light of its open support for the Federation. Soon after an armistice agreement is concluded between North Korea and South Korea, tensions erupt again because of the fighting between the two nations. The efforts of the military to overcome the new war are fruitless.
>
> **Five ICBMs are eventually launched from both sides, with targets being major cities around the world including Tokyo, London, Paris, New York and Moscow. The Tamura family stays behind amid the city's panic and holds a final dinner. That night, Tokyo is struck by the first of the five ICBMs and blown to pieces. The ground itself is torn open by the blast, enveloping much of the city's wreckage in molten lava. Tamura and his family are killed by the detonation over Tokyo as their house is blown away by the ensuing fireball.** Shortly after Tokyo is destroyed, the remaining four missiles impact their targets, obliterating each of them. The following morning, Takano and his crew change the course of their ship to travel towards Tokyo's ruins, prepared to die from exposure to the intense radioactive fallout. The ship's chaperone and Takano break down as the enduring events of what has happened become realized. The last shot shows Tokyo, now an immense crater, with the remains of the Diet Building at the center and a warning laid over the screen, asking for the events in this film never to happen.

As alluded to in the plot summary above, the film depicts the lead-up to a nuclear war from the POV of the Tamura family, and there's a scene in the last fifteen minutes of the film where they're sitting around a chabudai table having a final dinner. The father goes off to an upstairs bedroom to cry alone, and then the film cuts to shots of nuclear missiles being launched from various locations.

There's a shot of the dinner scene at around the 0:28 mark in the trailer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on the trailer, I cannot confirm yet that this is the movie I am looking for, but the plot summary sounds very promising. Also, the awkward German title of the movie seems to ring a bell.